# Record is Deleted still it is displaying in Look-up Field?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, error

I am running batch in the background where I am creating Master Accounts based on some criteria, however for testing purpose I deleted all Master Account records which were created from running the batch class.

Now when I am running the batch again, which will create the Master Accounts and will link to child accounts based on logic added, I observed that for few of the records on which Master Accounts were linked are referencing the old Master Account which I have Deleted.

I cleared all the data from my **Recycle Bin** 
[image]

But still when I go to child account record, I found that reference is still there for the record which I have deleted.
I am getting following message when I hover over record on detail page:
[image]

Why the value is not getting Clear from the Look-up field even though I have enabled option :
**What to do if the lookup record is deleted?   Clear the value of this field.**
Please suggest and advise.
Thanks,
Nachiket

Comment: Hi. What's the type of your field "Master Customer Account"? When you create a look up relationship, you can choose to clear the field when the master record is deleted.

Comment: Yes the option is enabled  for this field :- 
What to do if the lookup record is deleted? Clear the value of this field.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are trying to remove this ghost data...
Try running the same query with WHERE clause isDeleted = true, then maybe run a hard delete on the returned records.

Comment: I already cleared the data from Recycle Bin